To check whether first or last character of a string is x
I am trying to check whether the first or the last character of a string is x using zsh, and I get an error message instead:

./test.sh:2: bad substitution

What is the problem here?
string="2x3"
if [[ "${-n $string | head -c 1}" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "first character is x"
elif [[ "${-n $string | tail -c 1}" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "last character is x"
fi


Are you using bash or zsh?

@muru neither of those seem like a duplicate: i) the OP here is specifically asking about the first and last character and none of the dupes talk about the last; ii) the OP has an obvious syntax error that should be (and has been) explained. Granted, someone who knows shell scripting could figure it out from the answers eventually, but the OP here is clearly not familiar with the shell (which is fine, of course, we all start somewhere jsx97) so I doubt the dupes would help. Nor would they help others looking for "first and last only".

@terdon as you wish, just a note that https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523631/70524 covers the case of "first or last" which is what this question is about

Hmm yeah, true @muru. On the other hand that's hidden pretty low down. I didn't even see it, which could suggest that other wouldn't either.

@terdon Zsh. But I added the bash tag because I think many solutions can be "borrowed" from Bash.

Many can, but zsh has many things bash doesn't and lacks a few that bash has. They are not the same, and although similar, they shouldn't be treated as the same because that will lead to significant confusion.

Your expansion with ${ .. } does not run any code: it just produces a text string which is itself not even a valid command (it would need an echo, and also round  brackets).
There is a Bash expansion which produces substrings, without any need for external commands.
if [[ "${string: 0:1}" = "x" ]]  #.. offset from start.

if [[ "${string: -1:1}" = "x" ]]  #.. offset from end.

As @juliethefox notes, the = is a text comparison, and the == is a pattern comparison. If you wanted to combine the tests, this would be correct.
if [[ "${string}" == x* || "${string}" == *x ]]; then ...

Frequent use of external commands has a significant impact on Bash performance.

Many thanks. Out of curiosity, do you prefer single (=) instead of double (==) equation signs in shell comparisons?

@jsx97 What's the difference between single and double equal signs (=) in shell comparisons

Within double brackets = and == are the same: string=xray; [[ $string = x* ]] && echo yes

No, both = and == are pattern comparison in Korn-like shells. ${string:offset:length} is an operator from ksh93 originally, not bash. Here the question is for zsh. zsh only recently added that operator for compatibility with ksh, but has had $string[first,last] since before ksh93 even existed.

In any POSIXy shell, the case statement provides pattern matches (without running any external tools):
isx() {
    case $1 in
         x ) printf '%s\n' "'$1' is just a single x";;
        x*x) printf '%s\n' "'$1' starts and ends in x";;
         *x) printf '%s\n' "'$1' ends (only) in x";;
        x* ) printf '%s\n' "'$1' starts (only) with x";;
         * ) printf '%s\n' "'$1' doesn't start or end in x";;
    esac
}
isx foo
isx xfoo
isx foox
isx xfoox

(The patterns are checked in order, so x and x*x must be before the others, and * at the end.)
As it supports alternatives in one branch, you can also do this:
isx2() {
    case $1 in
        x*|*x) printf '%s\n' "'$1' starts and/or ends in x";;
          *  ) printf '%s\n' "'$1' doesn't start or end in x";;
    esac
}
isx2 foo
isx2 xfoo
isx2 foox
isx2 xfoox


To address your "What is the problem here?" question:

string="2x3"
if [[ "${-n $string | head -c 1}" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "first character is x"
elif [[ "${-n $string | tail -c 1}" == "x" ]]; then
  echo "last character is x"
fi


${x} is Parameter Expansion, i.e. expanding a variable into its value.
Clearly -n $string | head -c 1 is an invalid variable name.
You most likely were looking for $(...) Command Substitution but -n is not a command.

Since you're asking for zsh, you can of course use standard:
case $string in
  (x* | *x) echo "starts or ends in x (or both)";;
  (*) echo "Neither starts nor ends in x";;
esac

Where $string is matched against 2 patterns: x* and *x.
Or you could use a single (x*|*x) pattern (equivalent of ksh's @(x*|*x)) either with case or with the Korn-style [[ $string = pattern ]] operator:
if [[ $string = (x*|*x) ]] echo "starts or ends in x (or both)"

Or you could do:
if [[ $string[1] = x || $string[-1] = x ]] echo "starts or ends in x (or both)"

Above using the short forms of if. You can also of course use the long Bourne-style forms:
if [[ $string[1] = x || $string[-1] = x ]]; then
  echo "starts or ends in x (or both)"
else
  echo "Neither starts nor ends in x"
fi

To check whether $string starts or ends in x but not both (starts xor ends), zsh's arithmetic expressions have a logical ^^ xor operator, but not its [[ ... ]] construct.
Beside checking for (and reject) a x or x*x match specifically, you can do
if [[ $string = (x*[^x]|[^x]*x) ]]; then
  echo "starts or ends in x, not both"
else
  echo "Either starts and ends in x or neither"
fi

